# SQL Variable as an INSERT INTO Value

Tags: sql-server

All I'm trying to do is declare a variable called `@ReservationID`, initialize it to a value from the Reservation table where certain conditions exist, and use that value as a parameter to insert a new Folio table entry.  When I go to print my Folio table, the new table entry doesn't exist.  I've checked and ran the `SELECT` statement, and it comes up with the correct value based on the conditions.  Am I not initializing or passing the variable correctly?  What am I missing here?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @ReservationID smallint;
SET @ReservationID = (SELECT ReservationID FROM Reservation WHERE ReservationDate = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE()) AND CreditCardID = 1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Folio OFF
INSERT INTO Folio (ReservationID, GuestID, RoomID, QuotedRate, CheckinDate, Nights, Status, Comments, DiscountID)
VALUES(@ReservationID, 500, 20, 35.50, '07/24/2016', 3, 'R', NULL, 1);
```

Comment: In the results' messages tab what no of rows affected u get?

Comment: Code looks correct. Only requirement for @ReservationID is that subquery must return only one value (you may use top(1) for this). Is `ReservationID` is IDENTITY column?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be initializing or passing the variable correctly.

Refer MSDN [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) for assigning a variable to the value of an expression.

You need to correct the SET & IDENTITY_INSERT as below,

```
DECLARE @ReservationID smallint;
select @ReservationID = ReservationID FROM Reservation 
WHERE ReservationDate = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE()) AND CreditCardID = 1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Folio ON
INSERT INTO Folio (ReservationID, GuestID, RoomID, QuotedRate,  CheckinDate,Nights, Status, Comments, DiscountID)
VALUES(@ReservationID, 500, 20, 35.50, '07/24/2016', 3, 'R', NULL, 1);
```

Below is my quick test code,

```
create table Reservation(ReservationID smallint identity, CreditCardID int) 

insert into Reservation values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Reservation ON

DECLARE @ReservationID smallint;

select @ReservationID =  ReservationID FROM Reservation

insert into Reservation (ReservationID, CreditCardID)
values(@ReservationID,100)
```

Comment: In fact u introduced syntax error above with that `)` after 1. If it was syntax problem SSMS would state so. The `SET` syntax is correct that OP has used. That is not a problem. What u showed is just another syntax.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Vartak, There is a sytax difference for assigning a value to a variable and assigning expression value to a variable . Please refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx).

Comment: True and I know that. I meant using `select @variable` vs `set @variable = (select)` is not a cause of issue here because OP is able to get a proper `@variable` value.

Comment: The OP has history of not picking any answers for any of his several questions. See his/her profile. http://stackoverflow.com/users/6477547/amaidie90?tab=questions I think it's a waste of time answering his/her questions.